# Java Generics Reflection: Generic field type of subclass

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Given two classes like this:

```
class Example1<A,B> {

  public Map<A,B> someMap = new HashMap<A,B>();

}

class Example2 extends Example1<URL, URL> {


}
```

Is there any way using reflection that I can determine the component types of the Map for Example2?

I know I can do:

```
ParameterizedType t = (ParameterizedType) Example2.class.getFields()[0].getGenericType();
```

But from there, I can't seem to figure out that the two components are URLs.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just curious... What would `t` contain?

Comment: dont ever use java.net.URL as a key for HashMap!! it's evil because it potentially often calls hostsEqual() which performs network I/O (dns lookups)

Answer (score 7):

Darron is not completely correct.  The following will print out what you want:

```
ParameterizedType superClass = (ParameterizedType) Example2.class.getGenericSuperclass();
System.out.println(superClass.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
System.out.println(superClass.getActualTypeArguments()[1]);
```

Prints out:

```
class java.net.URL
class java.net.URL
```

Comment: To clarify on the "type erasure" point, all the generic type information is actually encoded in the Java .class file.  Where it's **not** encoded is within the runtime execution of a method.  That is why the information is accessible through reflection, but is not accessible through standard language constructs (i.e. new T[] or o instanceof T).

Comment: That gets you the type parameters used by Example2 for its *direct* superclass. But to solve the general problem this question poses, you need to find type parameters for an arbitrary superclass, plus then substitute type variables possibly deep inside the type of a field. getGenericSuperclass() is only a small first step to reach that goal. There are many (sometimes tricky) cases involved in building a full solution. I wouldn't recommend (re)implementing that  yourself unless you're *really* into generics.

Answer (score 1):

Because Java generics are implemented via "erasure", this information is not available at runtime through reflection.

EDIT: it seems I missed some detail of the question.  In this sort of specialized case the type information is available.

Comment: You'd be correct if the reflection began with calling `getClass` on an instance of `HashMap<URL, URL>` itself. Then Kirk's code would print something like `K` and `V` (the names of the type parameters; pretty useless). But because the reflection here begins with a class that *inherits* `HashMap<URL, URL>`, the types supplied for `K` and `V` are stored in the class metadata for `Example2`, and so Kirk's code has some information to read from.

Comment: Rob is asking about a class, not an object. The information is available at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not quite correct - you are returning the generic types of the Class, not of  "someMap" field type.

Of course, in the example given the arguments to someMap were , which are the same as the arguments to the class, but if someMap were defined with , and the map types were not both URL, then there is a question about how to map the generic type's parameters to the field's.

A better example might have been:

```
class Example1<A,B> {

  public Map<B,A> someMap = new HashMap<B,A>();

}

class Example2 extends Example1<URL, String> {


}
```

In this case, to answer the question of: what are someMap's types in Example2? The answer should be:

java.lang.String
java.net.URL

But, I still can't figure out how to get that.

Answer (score 1):

The Java reflection API does not have a method that directly gives what you want, but it does expose all the basic information needed to be able to *calculate* it with `Field.getGenericType()` and `Class.getGenericSuperclass()`.
But solving this problem in general for any class hierarchy and field type is not trivial.

To do this *calculating* you can use the [gentyref](http://code.google.com/p/gentyref/) library.
In your example, you can get the type of the someMap variable like this:

```
Type someMapType = GenericTypeReflector.getExactFieldType(
   Example2.class.getField("someMap"),
   Example2.class);
```

If enough information is available (and in Example2, it is), someMapType will be a [ParameterizedType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html). Then you can get the type of the key and the value like this:

```
((ParameterizedType)someMapType).getActualTypeArguments();
```

That will be array containing `URL.class` twice. Note that it can contain other things than classes too (another ParameterizedType for example). So if you want to do something non-trivial with that type (for example see if it's a supertype of another one), the other methods in GenericTypeReflector might come in handy too...

[I'm the author of gentyref]