# Getting generic information with reflection in Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get type of a generic parameter in java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)
>   [Java Generics Reflection: Generic field type of subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450505/java-generics-reflection-generic-field-type-of-subclass)

here's the thing. I have this code and I need to somehow get the generic information from the object.

```
Class A {
   public static String getGenericType(Object o) {
      ...
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      getGenericType(list); //this should return "Integer"
   }
}
```

I know you can get generic type from Field (Class.getField), but this is something different. Anybody knows how to get it done? Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, type erasure means that you don't get to know what's inside of <> at run-time.